# Select an element that comes before another element with the same class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to override the `margin-bottom: 20px;` that was set by the framework using it's predefined class `.alert` and set it back to `0` when the element is followed by another `.alert` element.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was set by the framework.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was set by the framework.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was set by the framework.</div>
  
</body>
```

I know that an adjacent selector can do a trick by selecting only a followed `.alert` element that is immediately preceded by another `.alert` element and set it's `margin-top` to `-20px` but this sounds dirty.

```css
.alert + .alert {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was retracted by the followed <code>margin-top: -20px;</code>.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was retracted by the followed <code>margin-top: -20px;</code>.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was not retracted because there's no followed <code>.alert</code> element.</div>
  
</body>
```

That CSS will retract the `margin-bottom: 20px;` of a preceded `.alert`, but is there a way to directly select the `.alert` if it comes before another `.alert` to override its `margin-bottom` to `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want

```css
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px</code> was overriden by <code>margin-bottom: 0</code>.</div>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px</code> was overriden by <code>margin-bottom: 0</code>.</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px</code> was overriden by <code>margin-bottom: 20px</code>.</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand your selectors and this will also do a trick but it looks like using the `.alert + .alert` selector is more better. Lets wait for the others if any.

Comment: Using the `.alert + .alert` selector is more better but accepted as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for a '[previous sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)' selector by the sounds of it which is not possible.

CSS can only select an element if it is a child or [adjacently](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) succeeding it. You cannot select an adjacent preceding element (or parent element) in CSS.

Your solution is perfectly acceptable. Negative margins are sometimes seen as 'dirty' for some reason but this is far from true and is [documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) officially.

> Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be
>   implementation-specific limits.

Your solution is the right one!

Comment: That was also my finding, lets see for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

To select elements that preceed others, use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has): `.alert:has(+ .alert)`. The selector provided to `:has` will be used for matching but will not cause the matched element to be selected.

```css
.alert:has(+ .alert) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was retracted by the followed <code>margin-top: -20px;</code>.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was retracted by the followed <code>margin-top: -20px;</code>.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">The <code>margin-bottom: 20px;</code> was not retracted because there's no followed <code>.alert</code> element.</div>
  
</body>
```